# Add reveal to Navigationviewitem when dragging an item over to it

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

How do I add reveal effect to `NavigationViewItem` when I am dragging an item over it and revert back to normal when I leave, similar to the pointer over reveal effect:
[image]

### Sample Code:

```
<muxc:NavigationViewItem
   BorderThickness="0.8"
   Content="Folder"
   Tag="FolderPath"
   AllowDrop="True"
   DragOver="NavigationViewItem_DragOver"
   Drop="NavigationViewItem_Drop"/>
```

Comment: Could you share your code that you have written. How do you implement NavigationViewItem  drag and drop?

Comment: I have added the sample code.

Comment: What Item you want to drop?

Comment: The navigationviewitems are folders and I want to drop storageitems in them.

Comment: For the testing NavigationViewItem has reveal effect when drop over.

Comment: Please check this [screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlLBgdBasvMrgYYAfMNjt1VEbmLMjA?e=K2zxBd).

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT Are you using `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem` or `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem`??

Comment: I'm using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem`.

Comment: I am using the WinUI version, hence I don't have that, anyway I can add the reveal effect to that??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218674/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-soumyamahunt).

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT I have found a working solution for this until this behavior is added by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is what I have come up with:

Modify the [default template available in WInUI repository](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/7acb9a7c5769af3e0b5dbe37c009dcafebef939c/dev/NavigationView/NavigationView.xaml#L526) and add the following `VisualStateGroup` in `VisualStateManager`:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="DragEnter">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <contract4Present:Setter Target="NVIRootGrid.(media:RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
            <Setter Target="NVIRootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" />
            <Setter Target="NVIRootGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
            <Setter Target="NavigationViewItemPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="DragLeave" />
    <VisualState x:Name="Drop" />
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Modify `NavigationViewItem` to handle `DragEnter` and `DragLeave` event:

```
<muxc:NavigationViewItem
   BorderThickness="0.8"
   Content="Folder"
   Tag="FolderPath"
   AllowDrop="True"
   DragEnter="NavigationViewItem_DragEnter"
   DragLeave="NavigationViewItem_DragLeave"
   DragOver="NavigationViewItem_DragOver"
   Drop="NavigationViewItem_Drop"/>
```

Change the `VisualState` in code behind:

```
    private void NavigationViewItem_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(sender as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem, "DragEnter", false);
    }

    private void NavigationViewItem_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(sender as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem, "DragLeave", false);
    }

    private async void NavigationViewItem_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(sender as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem, "Drop", false);

        // Handle drop
    }
```

Changing `VisualState` from xaml itself would be nice, but I haven't found any way for this.